# Printing an A3 (Word) document on an A4 printer

Tags: microsoft-word, printing

Is there a way to print an A3 sized document on an A4 printer?  So I want 2 A4 sheets per A3/Word page.  I can export to pdf / something else if Word can't do this.

(For anyone unfamiliar with A3 and A4, A4 is about the size of US Letter paper.  A3 is twice the size of A4)

Thanks!

Comment: Set your paper size to A3 - it should print out the docs on two seperate sheets of A4

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your printer doesn't support 'banner printing', here's a free application that will do the job (just save the document as A3 sized image):

**[Easy Poster Printer](http://www.gdsoftware.dk/products.aspx)** enables you easily to print posters of any size (max 20x20 meters). Just drag n drop your picture into the application and click print.

[image]

Another free (and open source) **[Poster Printer](http://posterprinter.sourceforge.net/)**:

[image]

Comment: the http://gdsoftware.dk/products.aspx (easy poster printer) is no longer valid

Comment: Fixed the broken link mentioned above.

Comment: [PosteRazor](http://posterazor.sourceforge.net) is another option.

Comment: Thanks @Gedrox PosteRazor is great and also doesn't print a watermark over the image (which an unregistered Easy Poster Printer does)

Answer (score 17):

As you suggested, exporting to a PDF first is another way this can be achieved *without the use of specialist software*.

**This feature requires [Adobe Reader](http://get.adobe.com/uk/reader/) X (10) or above.**

Open the print dialogue and click the poster printing button:

[image: Print dialogue]

With my A3 file, this by default put it onto a 2*2 grid (i.e. four bits of paper) which certainly isn't ideal.  However by experimenting with the value for **tile scale** you can adjust this to make it down to 2*1:

[image: Print dialogue with modified tile scale showing A3 document printing onto 2 A4 pages]

This does obviously slightly scale down the size of your image.  However, by reducing the size of the margins in your printer settings
 you can reduce this effect - with borderless printing Adobe Viewer is quite happy to fit the A3 page onto 2 A4 pages **with a maximum tile scale of 94%**.

[image: Final print dialogue showing that the scaling can be increased to prevent it getting too small]

Comment: _"without the use of other third party software."_ and then proceeds to use Adobe Reader..

Comment: @Joost haha fair point - more likely that a user will have Adobe Reader already installed than a specialist poster printing tool though!

Answer (score 0):

You will be able to do this if your printer supports the Banner function. Set this function to on and print the document, the printer will spread the document out over the paper size you have selected. I'd check it in print preview first to make sure its what you are after.